# Is it possible to use my HP multifunction printer from any computer on my LAN network?

Tags: networking, printing, hp

I installed my new HP printer (Color LaserJet Pro MFP M479fdn) on my main server (Ubuntu 18.04). It worked as is. I had nothing to do (i.e. it was automatically discovered and added to my system).

A few days later, I added it to another computer (Ubuntu 16.04) and it worked like a charm. I could print form that other computer.

Today, I wanted to print from my server and I could not see the printer. The installed printer said "Does not accept jobs".

Looking around for why that might be, I found a great pile of useless junk...

I tested with nmap since I should be able to find a few open ports:

- From the Ubuntu 16.04 (working)

  ```
  $ nmap -Pn -p 80,139,443,631,8080,9100,9220,9290,9500 192.168.2.189

  Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-21 13:36 PDT
  Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.189
  Host is up (0.59s latency).
  PORT     STATE  SERVICE
  80/tcp   open   http
  139/tcp  closed netbios-ssn
  443/tcp  open   https
  631/tcp  open   ipp
  8080/tcp open   http-proxy
  9100/tcp open   jetdirect
  9220/tcp closed unknown
  9290/tcp closed unknown
  9500/tcp closed ismserver

  Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.35 seconds
  ```
- From the server (Ubuntu 18.04--failing)

  ```
  $ nmap -Pn -p 80,139,443,631,8080,9100,9220,9290,9500 192.168.2.189

  Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-21 13:47 PDT
  Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.189
  Host is up.

  PORT     STATE    SERVICE
  80/tcp   filtered http
  139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
  443/tcp  filtered https
  631/tcp  filtered ipp
  8080/tcp filtered http-proxy
  9100/tcp filtered jetdirect
  9220/tcp filtered unknown
  9290/tcp filtered unknown
  9500/tcp filtered ismserver

  Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.11 seconds
  ```

  **Note:** The STATUS column changes between `filtered` and `closed`, but in most cases `nmap` tells me `filtered`.

As we can see, from the computer where CUPS says the printer is not accessible, the ports are closed.

Is there something in the printer that decided to block my main server? I could not see anything wrong in there. Also the printer has to use my main server to gets it's IP address through the DHCP server. So it's still talking to my main server, but blocks all the ports...

Just in case, I wide opened the firewall between the printer and my main server and it's still not letting me do anything. Not just that, but since it worked before, I don't get it. Would the second computer cause such problems?!? I also disconnected the printer power and restarted. It made no difference. I also tried to diconnect/reconnect the network cable and I can see that the DHCP re-assigns the expected IP address just fine. So the print CAN talk to my server, it just blocks inbound traffic but why?!?

So I'm not too sure what to try next. What would you do to make the printer accept any one of my Ubuntu computers?

---

P.S. Just in case, from the computer which is allowed, I verified the network settings, including the firewall and the printer is clearly not blocking anything that I can see. The firewall is actually not enabled and all the services on the printer are enabled. Also, the ping command works:

```
$ ping 192.168.2.189
PING 192.168.2.189 (192.168.2.189) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.189: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=53.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.189: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.287 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.189: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.849 ms

--- 192.168.2.189 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.287/18.353/53.923/25.152 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you reviewed your networking privacy settings for public and private networks? have you maybe added any VPN or other anti-virus/malware apps or software? that's 1st thing to pop in my mind.

Comment: My network setup has not changed. No VPN and I've not heard of anti-virus/malware under Linux.

Comment: OK. maybe an update of drivers and utilities can fix this problem. I had similar issues with a scanner that believed it was in Canada but I'm pretty sure it was in South Africa also update time for all network connections etc

Comment: Okay, I'm pretty sure I understand what happened... I now force the IP address for the printer, but I probably did not before and it selected a "valid" IP (one that would go through the firewall as expected). I just added a couple of rule in the OUTPUT and it works as expected! :-) So you were correct, not a VPN but still a firewall rule that was in the way.